# Preprocessing data in Python before passing it to class constructor

Tags: python, constructor

Is it good style to create a separate method, in which I preprocess data, before I pass it to the constructor (in case the preprocessing is cumbersome), like so:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, input, more_input):
        self.value = self.prepare_value(input, more_input)

    def prepare_value(self, input, more_input): 
    #here I actually do some nontrivial stuff, over many lines  
    #for brevity I'm illustrating just a short, one-line operation
        value = (input + more_input)/2
        return value


print(C(10, 33).value) # has value 21.5
```

Comment: Yes that seems sensible. Note that you haven't quite got your terminology right. You are not doing the preprocessing before the constructor. You are doing it in the constructor. Although its never so clear cut to say its always sensible or its always not sensible. It depends on what your class does and if you are assigning one class too much responsibility and coupling it to too much other functionality by requiring a large quantity of pre processing in its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to do it like this, then I'd suggest two things.

1. Make the `prepare_value()` method a [static method](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods) by decorating with the `@staticmethod` decorator. Since it's not making any changes to the instance of the class itself, just returning a value then you shouldn't be making it a method of the instance. Hence, `@staticmethod`.
2. Signify that the method should only be used internally by using the name `_prepare_value()`. This doesn't actually make it private, but it's a well recognized convention to say to other developers (i.e. future you) "this method isn't designed to be used externally".

Overall my suggestion would be:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, input, more_input):
        self.value = self._prepare_value(input, more_input)

    @staticmethod
    def _prepare_value(input, more_input): 
        value = (input + more_input)/2
        return value
```